# Changing the format of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, utf-8, cells

I have an Excel worksheet where one of the cells has the string "\xab\xcd\xef" etc. It seems as if Excel is taking this as the ASCII string "\xab\xcd\xef". How do I make Excel treat it as a binary string with the bytes 0xab 0xcd 0xef so I can convert it to UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Use SUBSTITUTE, eg if \xab\xcd\xef is in `A1`:

> =SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\"," 0")

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating all the bytes whose values appear in a cell into a string may be tricky, but this may be part of the answer: If cell `B2` contains `53`, then `=CHAR(HEX2DEC(B2))` will evaluate
to the character `S` –– because hex 0x53 = decimal 83, which is the ASCII value for ‘S’. 
And, of course, you can extract the `ab` from `\xab\xcd\xef` with `MID(…, 3, 2)`.